# How can I call a List or Function before onInit() function. Need to prioritize a List of value before onInit() is called in Dart. Flutter-Dart-Sqlite

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, initialization, return

I've been trying to get a list of values from one point(savedList) to Body of the application.
This is a Quiz Application built using Flutter-Dart-Sqlite. When I pass a list of data that is pre-assigned as [] when declared a value does not return any value. So the problem here is that onInit() function is called before this particular value is passed.

While calling the savedList which is globally declared as empty array[] and is assigned a set of Inserted value does not return the expected value. The onInit() function from controller is called  initially so the value that I get does not load, it gets loaded after the execution of onInit() function. How can I call this savedList before onInit() and is there a way to prioritize the passed value.

```js
QuestionController Class that has savedList

import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/database/dbconn.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/models/Questions.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/screens/score/score_screen.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';


class QuestionController extends GetxController
    with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {

  static Database _database;
  static DbConn dbConn = DbConn();
  static List savedList = [];

  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  Animation get animation => this._animation;

  PageController _pageController;

  PageController get pageController => this._pageController;

  bool _isAnswered = false;

  bool get isAnswered => this._isAnswered;

  int _correctAns;

  int get correctAns => this._correctAns;

  int _selectedAns;

  int get selectedAns => this._selectedAns;

  RxInt _questionNumber = 1.obs;

  RxInt get questionNumber => this._questionNumber;

  int _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

  int get numOfCorrectAns => this._numOfCorrectAns;

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 30), vsync: this);
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        update();
      });

    _animationController.forward().whenComplete(nextQuestion);
    _pageController = PageController();

    String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    _database = await openDatabase(
      join(databasesPath, 'Question.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        debugPrint('called getQues inside DB table creation');
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE QuesTable(id INTEGER, question TEXT, options TEXT, answer_index INTEGER)",
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
    final Database db = _database;

    for (int i = 0; i < DbConn.sample_data.length; i++) {
      var onlyQuesFor = DbConn.sample_data[i]['question'];
      debugPrint("Latest onlyQuesFor: $onlyQuesFor");
      var exId = DbConn.sample_data[i]['id'];
      var exQuestion = DbConn.sample_data[i]['question'];
      var exOptions = DbConn.sample_data[i]['options'];
      var exAnswerIndex = DbConn.sample_data[i]['answer_index'];

      int insertId1 = await _database.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO QuesTable(id, question, options, answer_index) VALUES($exId, "$exQuestion", "$exOptions", $exAnswerIndex)');
      debugPrint('InsertedValue: $insertId1');
    }

    List<Map> list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM QuesTable');
    savedList = list;
    debugPrint('SavedQuestionList: $list');

    super.onInit();
  }


  List<Question> _questions = savedList
      .map(
        (question) =>
        Question(
            id: question['id'],
            question: question['question'],
            options: question['options'],
            answer_index: question['answer_index']),
  ).toList();
  List<Question> get questions => _questions;


  checkSavedlist() async {
    debugPrint('getSavedListFromDBConnect checkSavedlist: ${ await DbConn.savedList}');
    return DbConn.savedList;
  }




  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    checkSavedlist();
    _animationController.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void checkAns(Question question, int selectedIndex) {
    _isAnswered = true;
    _correctAns = question.answer_index;
    _selectedAns = selectedIndex;

    if (_correctAns == _selectedAns) _numOfCorrectAns++;

    _animationController.stop();
    update();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      nextQuestion();
    });
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    if (_questionNumber.value != _questions.length) {
        _isAnswered = false;
      _pageController.nextPage(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.ease);

      _animationController.reset();

      _animationController.forward().whenComplete(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      Get.to(ScoreScreen());
    }
  }

   updateTheQnNum(int index) {
    _questionNumber.value = index + 1;
    return _questionNumber.value;
  }
}
```

This is the Body() function where I call the passed value,

```js
Body()

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/controllers/question_controller.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/database/dbconn.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/models/Album.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/models/Questions.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/screens/quiz/quiz_screen.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'progress_bar.dart';
import 'question_card.dart';

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
  debugPrint('fetchAlbumWorking: $response');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

Future<Album> futureAlbum;

class Body extends StatelessWidget{
  const Body({
    Key key,
    FutureBuilder<Album> child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _questionController = Get.put(QuestionController());
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/endless-constellation.svg",
            fit: BoxFit.fill),
        SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
                child: ProgressBar(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
                child: Obx(
                  () => Text.rich(
                    TextSpan(
                      text:
                          "Question ${_questionController.questionNumber.value}",
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .headline4
                          .copyWith(color: kSecondaryColor),
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                          text: "/${_questionController.questions.length}",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .headline5
                              .copyWith(color: kSecondaryColor),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(thickness: 1.5),
              SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding),
              Expanded(
                child: PageView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _questionController.pageController,
                  onPageChanged: _questionController.updateTheQnNum,
                  itemCount: _questionController.questions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => QuestionCard(
                    question: _questionController.questions[index],
                    // album: _questionController.questions[index],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

}
```